# Numerical solve question

Tags: equation-solving, bugs, trigonometry

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.4.0**

---

Why does this work?

```
Solve[5 Tan[t] + 9 == 0 && 0 <= t < 2 Pi , t]

{{t -> π - ArcTan[9/5]}, {t -> 2 π - ArcTan[9/5]}}
```

But this doesn't.

```
NSolve[5 Tan[t] + 9 == 0 && 0 <= t < 2 Pi , t]

{}
```

Comment: It does work if I do this: `NSolve[5 Tan[t]+9==0&&0<=t<2 Pi,t,Complexes]`. So you have to allow complex values to get the real solutions. I think that's strange.

Comment: `NSolve[5 Tan[t] + 9 == 0 && 0 <= t <= 6, t]` also works :)

Comment: `NSolve[5 Tan@t + 9 == 0 && 0 <= t <= 2 Pi]` Also works ! :=)

Comment: @belisariusisforth. What?!

Comment: @march At least on V9 the three alternatives above work like a charm. But the OP version doesn't

Comment: @belisariusisforth "Fortunately," `NSolve[5 Tan@t + 9 == 0 && 0 <= t <= 2 Pi]` does **not** work here - otherwise I'd be really confused.

Comment: @Jens My pleasure  :) ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4gaLh.png)

Comment: @belisariusisforth OK, I give up any attempt at an explanation. `NSolve` doesn't even have `HoldFirst` attribute...

Comment: Of course, a reformulation of the problem works: `NSolve[5 Sin[t] + 9 Cos[t] == 0 && 0 <= t < 2 Pi]`.

Comment: The question is out of scope for this site. The answer to this question requires either advice from Wolfram support or the services of a professional magician :)

Comment: `With[{e = 6 $MachineEpsilon},  NSolve[5 Tan[t] + 9 == 0 && 0 <= t < 2 Pi - e, t]]` also works and `e` has the smallest value I was able to find that could make it happen.

Comment: I have sent a query on this matter to WRI tech support. Will report their reaction.

Comment: Fixed in the development version today.

Answer (score 4):

As I noted in a comment to the question, I made a query about this issue to WRI tech support. I have now received a reply. I quote the relevant part.

> It does appear that NSolve is not behaving properly, and I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided. I would like to include a link to the stack exchange article; do you have the stack exchange article number?

I have sent a reply giving the URL of this question as requested.

Also, on the basis of this reply from WRI, I am marking the question with [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs).

#### Update

I received another email from WRI tech support concerning this issue saying the developers have agreed to fix it.

> Thank you for the link to the article. I have heard back from our development team and a fix for this issue is expected in a future release.

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been fixed in Mathematica [10.4.0](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn104.html).

```
NSolve[5 Tan[t] + 9 == 0 && 0 <= t < 2 Pi, t]

(* {{t -> 2.07789}, {t -> 5.21949}} *)
```